# Expansion and orthogonality

Tags: orthogonality

It is stated various places that as the Legendre functions
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty P_m(\cos\theta)
$$
are orthogonal, this enables us to expand any function of $\theta$ into a set of these functions.

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not orthogonality that lets us expand. What orthogonality does is lets us expand *easily*, because the coefficients for a function $f$ must be exactly

$$
c_m = \langle f, P_m(\cos \theta) \rangle
$$

The factor the a function $f$ can be expanded at all comes because these functions form a basis for the set of all functions. (Except that's not quite true: you need to limit to integrable functions, and they probably need to be continuous almost everywhere, and equality holds only on a set whose complement has measure zero, and ... a whole lot of other technical constraints.) More particularly, the existence of an expansion comes from the functions *spanning* the relevant space of function. The uniqueness of the expansion comes because they're a basis. Orthogonality just makes writing down the coefficients easy.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer, this moved me in right direction of understanding :-)